# Using Getline on a Binary File

Tags: c++, string, binaryfiles, getline, null-terminated

I have read that [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) behaves as an unformatted input function. Which I believe should allow it to be used on a binary file. Let's say for example that I've done this:

```
ofstream ouput("foo.txt", ios_base::binary);
const auto foo = "lorem ipsum";

output.write(foo, strlen(foo) + 1);
output.close();

ifstream input("foo.txt", ios_base::binary);
string bar;

getline(input, bar, '\0');
```

Is that breaking any rules? It seems to work fine, I think I've just traditionally seen arrays handled by writing the size and then writing the array.

Comment: It works in your simple case, and other equally simple cases. It won't work generally. Remember that binary files can contain any bytes in any order, including zeroes (which is what `'\0'` is) anywhere, especially where you don't expect it. Using "text" functions on binary data will, sooner or later, cause you more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: In two words: _Silly idea_!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well that is the reason that I posted it here. So, I'm working in a code base that's doing this. Why do you say that it's a silly idea? (As in how much effort should I expend converting this over to a size and array?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not breaking any rules that I can see.

Yes, it's more common to write an array with a prefixed size, but using a delimiter to mark the end can work perfectly well also. The big difference is that (like with a text file) you have to read through data to find the next item. With a prefixed size, you can look at the size, and skip directly to the next item if you don't need the current one. Of course, you also need to ensure that if you're using something to mark the end of a field, that it can never occur inside the field (or come up with some way of detecting when it's inside a field, so you can read the rest of the field when it does).

Depending on the situation, that can mean (for example) using Unicode text. This gives you a lot of options for values that can't occur inside the text (because they aren't legal Unicode). That, on the other hand, would also mean that your "binary" file is really a text file, and has to follow some basic text-file rules to make sense.

Which is preferable depends on how likely it is that you'll want to read random pieces of the file rather than reading through it from beginning to end, as well as the difficulty (if any) of finding a unique delimiter and if you don't have one, the complexity of making the delimiter recognizable from data inside a field. If the data is only meaningful if written in order, then having to read it in order doesn't really pose a problem. If you can read individual pieces meaningfully, then being able to do so much more likely to be useful.

In the end, it comes down to a question of what you want out of your file being "binary'. In the typical case, all 'binary" really means is that what end of line markers that might be translated from a new-line character to (for example) a carriage-return/line-feed pair, won't be. Depending on the OS you're using, it might not even mean that much though--for example, on Linux, there's normally no difference between binary and text mode at all.

Comment: That's a really excellent point about line endings, I hadn't considered that. But if I'm in windows, are you saying the line ending style differs between what's in memory and what's written to a file? I thought the conversion would have happened before I ever bothered to write to file.

Comment: In text mode the conversion happens as you write to the file.

Comment: So you're telling me that I carry it around in memory as 1 character, but when I go to write it out they decided to make it 2 characters? So it's just a completely pointless second step?

Comment: Not pointless. It produces a text file as the platform and its programs expect it to look so you can open it in things like notepad,  for example.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are no rules broken and you'll get away with that just fine, except that may miss the precision of reading *binary* from a stream object.

With binary input, you usually want to know how many characters were read successfully, which you can obtain afterwards with [`gcount()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount)... Using [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) will not reflect the bytes read in [`gcount()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount).

Of cause, you can simply get such info from the size of the string you passed into `std::getline`. But the stream will no longer encapsulate the number of bytes you consumed in the last Unformatted Operation